# GetConnection always retun NULL value , JAVA11

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, xampp

im using OpenJDK11 and Netbeand IDE 11.0 on ubuntu 18.04.3

I have a method to connect my application to my database, like this

```
Connection connection ;
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

public boolean Conexion(String user,String pass){
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        System.out.println(connection);
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also have another method to obtain the connection

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    return connection;
}
```

but when i try to do this

```
public class principal extends Conexion {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (new Conexion().Conexion("root", "")) {
        System.out.println(new Conexion().getConnection());
    }
}
}
```

I get this output

```
run:
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@4141d797
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I used the connection method as login,
The user has a login screen, where you must enter your username and password, if this user is registered in the xampp server, you can enter, and as you can see, in the example, I entered the username and the default password of xampp , and At first it works, but the getConnection method returns null and I don't understand why.

thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code

```
if (new Conexion().Conexion("root", "")) {
    System.out.println(new Conexion().getConnection());
}
```

The first `Conexion` object is a different object to the second - hence the return value of `getConnection()` has not been initialised

Comment: the getConnection method returns the same variable that is printed in the 'Conexion' method, I mean that these two methods use the same variable, so the getConnection method should return a valid connection, rigth?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I feel very ashamed really hahahaha thanks for your time ILV